# apply CSS to any element using class dependent on other class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap` `navbar`, I've 2 logos on the `navbar`.

Is it possible to have first logo when `navbar` is `collapsed and not expanded`, and other logo when navbar is `collapsed and expanded`. I have tried the code after inspecting element, but it didn't work.

`CSS`:

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
    .logo1 { display:none;}
    .logo2 {display:block;}
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top header-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="Logo" href="index.php">
          <img src="logo6.jpg" class="logo1 visible-xs" />
          <img src="logo.jpg" class="logo2 hidden-xs" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        ...basic navbar code...
```

Please help.

Comment: By using `media-query`, yes it is possible.

Comment: can you please guide me how? THE CODE? :)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. i'd suggest that you do your research and then, if you can't get **your** attempt to work, ask again.

Comment: Is using javascript an option?

Comment: yeah, any option, just wanna do this

Comment: Hmmm, I am thinking of a CSS only approach. Let me try if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pure CSS approach:**

You can use the attributes of the button to detect if the navbar is collapsed or expanded in smaller screens.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  button[aria-expanded="true"] ~ .navbar-brand.expanded-logo {
    display: block; /* If aria-expanded is set to true, show the logo for expanded state */
  }
  button[aria-expanded="false"] ~ .navbar-brand.collapsed-logo {
    display: block; /* If aria-expanded is set to false, show the logo for collapsed state */
  }
  button[aria-expanded="true"] ~ .navbar-brand.collapsed-logo {
    display: none; /* Hide the collapsed state logo when the expanded state logo is shown */
  }
}
.expanded-logo {
  display: none; /* Show only one logo on larger screen, hide logo by default */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div data-example-id="navbar-static-top" class="bs-example bs-navbar-top-example">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button aria-expanded="false" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-8" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand collapsed-logo">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/333">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand expanded-logo">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/666">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-8" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this, but i want to change logo when navbar is collapsed and not expanded, and other logo when navbar is collapsed and expanded. I have edited my question, may be i have missed my point before

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i was looking for :)

Comment: Glad it helped, Syed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($('.navbar').hasClass('in')) {
    //do something with first/second logo

  } else{
    //do something with first/second logo

  };
});
```